# why can't I call a function from another function in python. function undefined error

Tags: python

I have a really simple project due in a discrete math class and I'm having trouble coding it in python (yes I have to use python).

```
def factorial(number):
    x = 1
    y = 2
    while y <= number:
       x *= y
       y += 1
    return x

def choose(n, k):
    total = (factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*(factorial(n-k))))
    return total
```

The goal is to show the numerical value of n choose k. and this code makes sense to me (and I tested the factorial and it works correctly) but I get the error "name 'factorial' is not defined" which doesn't make sense b/c it's clearly defined and its in the same class.

Comment: Neither of these functions should be in a class.

Comment: Where do you see a python `class`? I understood it's homework for a "math class" as in school class, not as in object oriented programming

Comment: "which doesn't make sense b/c it's clearly defined and its in the same class"

Comment: Ah. sorry. Then OP should update the code example.

Comment: And I fully agree. No class needed here, python is not java.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple functions as these do not belong in classes in python.

Classes are for keeping state together with methods to alter this state, you do not have state to keep track of, so do not use a class.

You factorial functions also will not work. You do `x *= sec` and `return fir` which are not defined.

Comment: thanks i didnt realize i didnt need a class. im used to java. as for the factorial function i just forgot to change fir to x and the sec to y

Comment: You could do `for y in range(number, 1, -1)` and get rid of two lines ;)

Comment: Btw. Are you required to implement the factorial yourself? If not, use `from math import factorial`: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html

Comment: i'm not sure if we're required to use our own but we are required to create our own so I figured I might as well use it since it's there.

Comment: Then go for it ;)

Answer (score 3):

If it's a *class method* of the same class, you have to use `ClassName.factorial()`, or `self.factorial(...)` if it is a method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read more about 
[Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)  ,
Your implementation isn't a perfect one as you have to get the factorial of 3 different numbers n , k , n-k .

[image]

=

[image]

Here is the implementation of the second formula and comparison in the runtime between them .

```
from math import factorial
import time

def mine_choose(n, k) :
    _n = n
    numerator = 1
    while _n >= n-k+1 :
        numerator *= _n
        _n -= 1
    dominator = factorial(k)
    return numerator/dominator

def your_choose(n, k):
    total = (factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*(factorial(n-k))))
    return total



timer = time.clock()
print('mine_choose : ' , mine_choose(100000,3))
print ("Total time mine_choose : ", time.clock() - timer)


timer = time.clock()
print('your choose : ' , your_choose(100000,3))
print ("Total time of your_choose : ", time.clock() - timer)
```

**The result is :**

```
mine_choose :  166661666700000.0
Total time of mine_choose :  0.0013608076337989215
your choose :  166661666700000.0
Total time of your_choose :  0.5442163699942707
```

Comment: that's pretty cool we were never taught about that second formula in my class so I never even thought about that thanks for the advice.